# How to get updating row ID in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Employee`

```
  Emp_Id  Name
  1       XYZ
  2       ABC
```

and another table `DivisionInfo`

```
  DivisionID  Division  Emp_Id
       1       mmm          1
       2       nnnn         1
       3       oooo         1
```

I need to write a trigger to rollback updates of the `Employee` table, if the `Emp_Id` is present in the `DivisionInfo` table. In this case `Emp_Id = 1`.

How to get the row id of the row being updated in the SQL trigger?

This is my trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EmployeeTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Employee]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
   IF((SELECT COUNT([DivisionID ]) 
       FROM [DivisionInfo] AS D 
       INNER JOIN Employee AS E ON D.[Emp_Id] = E.Emp_Id
       WHERE D.[Emp_Id] = E.Emp_Id) > 0)
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Testing', 10, 1); 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      RETURN
   END
```

Here it's always true

Comment: I do find it odd that if you want to update an employees name, you can't do it if he is assigned to a division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[EmployeeTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Employee]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
IF((
    SELECT COUNT([DivisionID ])
    FROM [DivisionInfo] D
    JOIN INSERTED I ON I.[Emp_Id] = D.[Emp_Id])>0)
BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Testing', 10, 1); 
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     RETURN
END
```

Comment: YOu need to understand one thing about a trigger, you can NEVER assume only one record is being processed. So you don;t think of getting the row id of the row beuing updated, a million rows might be being updated.  Right now the trigger will rollback all records if any of then are in the Division info table and if you get a multiple record update some of which are in the Division table and some of which are not, this may not be what you want. You always have to plan for  (and test) multiple record updates in a trigger.